# WildFly 9 load balancing with mod_cluster

Tags: apache, load-balancing, wildfly, mod-cluster

I'm trying to configure load balancing with jboss wildfly running on windows for the first time. I d'ont have an experience with jboss or apache httpd. i have installed apache httpd and mod_cluster, than i added the required modules from mod_cluster to appache httpd then in httpd.conf  i added this configuration :

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
<Location /mod_cluster_manager>
      SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 127.0.0.
</Location>
 KeepAliveTimeout 60
 MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
 ManagerBalancerName mycluster
 ServerAdvertise On
</VirtualHost>
```

When i put a clustered ejb application in the deployments and start the server with default standlone-ha.xml values i can access to  /mod_cluster_manager but there is no node detected
I don't know if theres is further configuration i found a tutorial but it's not well explained anything can help  thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some configuration, so there is no communication between Apache and Wildfly currently.

First, change the Port of your virtual host above to 6666 (common default for mod_cluster-manager virtual host) or anything other than 8080. You seem to be running Wildfly and Apache on the same host, 8080 is Wildfly's default HTTP listener Port, so instead of changing Wildfly's default, use something else for Apache.

Then you have two options:

a) enable MCPM in Apache's part of mod_cluster to get multicast auto-configuration

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:6666>
  ...
  EnableMCPMReceive
</VirtualHost>
```

b) don't use multicast, and explicitly set the proxies in Wildfly's standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:2.0">
   <mod-cluster-config proxies="127.0.0.1:6666" ...>
   ...
   </mod-cluster-config>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: Have you tried cluster deployment for JBoss EAP 7 in standalone mode using Apache HTTPD mod_cluster. I have questions which I have not found answers in red had documentation for JBoss. I am sharing the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454068/load-balancing-cluster-not-working-with-apache-http-server-2-4-6-and-jboss-eap-7